# The function for tensor value generates this Error: 'false_fn' must be callable

Tags: python, tensorflow, autoencoder, activation-function, relu

I am creating a function that takes a tensor value and returns the result by applying the following formulation, There are 3 conditions so I am using @tf.functions.

```
def Spa(x):
    x= tf.convert_to_tensor(float(x), dtype=tf.float32)
    p= tf.convert_to_tensor(float(0.05), dtype=tf.float32)
    
    p_dash=x
    K = p*logp_dash
    Ku=K.sum(Ku)
    
    Ku= tf.convert_to_tensor(float(Ku), dtype=tf.float32)
    

    y= tf.convert_to_tensor(float(0), dtype=tf.float32)
    def a(): return tf.constant(0)

    r = tf.case([(tf.less(x, y), a), (tf.greater(x, Ku), a)], default=x, exclusive=False)
    return r
```

The code generates the following error:
**'false_fn' must be callable.**
I did many conversions, int to float and float to int but don't know what is the issue.

Comment: `must be callable` means it has to be function (or something with defined `()` operator).

Comment: `def y(): return tf.constant(0)
    y = y()
    y = tf.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=tf.int32) ` Adding this still throws error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be something like this.

```
x = tf.where(x < 0, tf.zeros_like(x), x)
p = 0.05
p_hat = x
KL_divergence = p * (tf.math.log(p / p_hat)) + (1 - p) * (tf.math.log(1 - p / 1 - p_hat))
x = tf.where(x < KL_divergence, tf.zeros_like(x), x)
return x
```

Answer (score 0):

In `tf.case` x should be a function not a tensor. As [described in TF page](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/case#expressions_2).

```
def f1(): return tf.constant(17)
def f2(): return tf.constant(23)
def f3(): return tf.constant(-1)
r = tf.case([(tf.less(x, y), f1), (tf.greater(x, z), f2)], default=f3, exclusive=True)
```

You can see that `f3` here is also a function.